# Sydney to Tokyo Narita

Tags: transit, short-connections, bne

I have booked a flight from Sydney to Tokyo Narita. However I have a stopover in Brisbane. Basically I have 1 hour and 30 minutes to get to the right gate in Brisbane. I'll need to change from the domestic to the international terminal.

Is this enough time? Hopefully I'll get all my boarding passes in Sydney, so I'll just need to arrive at the gate once I get to Brisbane, plus go though security.

Comment: One ticket or two separate bookings ?

Comment: One booking, same airline

Answer (score 1):

Should be fine. Your bags will be checked through and since your first leg is domestic you can just walk off the plane and hop on the bus. Runs every 10 minutes with about 10  minutes travel time (https://bne.com.au/passenger/to-and-from/terminal-transfers).

Worst case you arrive in the international terminal 1 hour before departure. Unless there is a major delay in security and/or passport control, you should be able to make it. If you don't the airlines will put you on the next available flight for free.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Would they put me in the next flight with the same airline or would they offer a flight with a different airline that they are partners with? I think that's the only flight from that airline that day

Comment: @Robert The only airline that flies from Brisbane to Tokyo is Qantas, and even they don't fly daily.  You would likely be rerouted through another airport connection on Qantas or Jetstar.

Comment: Another possibility: they put you up for the night in a hotel and put you on the same flight the next day.